# Clock hand rotation reverting back to original position at 360deg

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I was following this challenge which ended with fixing this clocks hands.

Whenever the second's hand reaches the 12 o'clock position, the entire animation restarts but pulls the hand backwards so the next tick at 1-second isnt seamless, and it looks ugly.

how can I achieve this?

```js
 const secondHand = document.querySelector('.second-hand');
 function setDate(){
 const now = new Date();
          const seconds = now.getSeconds();
          const secondsDegrees = ((seconds / 60) * 360) + 90;
          secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondsDegrees}deg)`;
}

 setInterval(setDate, 1000);
      setDate();
```

```css
    .clock {
      width: 30rem;
      height: 30rem;
      border: 20px solid white;
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin: 50px auto;
      position: relative;
      padding: 2rem;
      box-shadow:
        0 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
        inset 0 0 0 3px #EFEFEF,
        inset 0 0 10px black,
        0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

    }

    .clock-face {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      transform: translateY(-3px); /* account for the height of the clock hands */
    }

    .hand {
      width: 50%;
      height: 6px;
      background: black;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      transform-origin: 100%;
      transform: rotate(90deg);
      transition: all 0.05s;
      transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.38, 2.9, 0.58, 1);
}
```

```html
 <div class="clock">
      <div class="clock-face">
        <div class="hand hour-hand"></div>
        <div class="hand min-hand"></div>
        <div class="hand second-hand"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
 <br>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: @Barmar added a snippet

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your seconds hand to 360 degrees, disable its transition, set it to 0 degrees, then enable its transition. Note that you should only disable the transition **after** the previous transition is over:

```
function setDate() {
  const now = new Date();
  const seconds = now.getSeconds();
  const secondsDegrees = ((seconds / 60) * 360) + 90;
  if(secondsDegrees == 0) {
    secondHand.style.transform = "rotate(360deg)";
    setTimeout(function() {
      secondHand.style.transition = "0s";
      secondHand.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
      secondHand.style.transition = "";
    },50);
  } else {
    secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondsDegrees}deg)`;
  }
}
```

You will probably need to do this for the minutes and hours hands too.

Comment: You need to show your code so that I can know what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: i added a code snippet with the exact problem above

Comment: Oh my, a typo: `secondDegrees -> secondsDegrees`.